# "To follow his example, we will best be rewarded if we strive instead to listen always to the dictates of reason."

Tags: adverbs

I got this sentence of a book.

> To follow his example, we will best be rewarded if we strive instead to listen always to the dictates of reason.

The position of the adverb "always" seems odd to me, Is that so because the emphasis is on the main verb (after the main verb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fairly poetic phrasing, so it can sound a bit strange! You could think of it as putting more emphasis on *what* you're always listening to, rather than the *act* of always listening, but the word order the author's using suggests it's just their writing style (see also "best be rewarded", "strive instead").

Answer (score 0):

There is an old "rule" of **style** not to separate "to" and the verb in an infinitive. It is **NOT** a rule of grammar. Nor, in my opinion, is it a universally valid guide to good style.

Personally, I do tend to avoid "splitting infinitives" because I like to emphasize the verb as you mentioned. Moreover, it makes me think about what is the exact thought that I am trying to convey. But I split infinitives willingly if that is what sounds natural and accords with my intended emphasis.

Here is a good example where splitting the infinitive is far better than the awkward construction actually used.

> To follow his example, we will best be rewarded if we strive instead to always listen to the dictates of reason.

Alternatively, it makes more sense in my opinion to modify "strive" if we want to admit that "always listening" is a human impossibility. In which case, the whole issue of a split infinitive never even arises.

> To follow his example, we will best be rewarded if we always strive instead to listen to the dictates of reason.

Or, if we want to make it more of a command than an exhortation, the need for "strive" disappears along with the issue of a split infinitive.

> To follow his example, we will best be rewarded if we always listen to the dictates of reason.